# SomeClass.<OtherClass>someMethod() syntax meaning

Tags: java, gradle

I have come across a curious syntax today. The code is from Gradle's source files you can find it in `src/core-impl/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/configurations/DefaultConfiguration.java`

```
private class ConfigurationResolvableDependencies implements ResolvableDependencies {
    public FileCollection getFiles() {
        return DefaultConfiguration.this.fileCollection(Specs.<Dependency>satisfyAll());
    }
}
```

Is someone able to explain the purpose of this strange generics syntax. If this is a repeat, then please forgive me as i do not know what to call this for searching purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, just read the [documentation on the oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), This type of syntax is referred to as **Type Witnessing** and it is used when a generic method with generic types is defined as so:

```
 public class BoxDemo {
  public static <U> void addBox(U u, List<Box<U>> boxes) {
  Box<U> box = new Box<>();
  box.set(u);
  boxes.add(box);
  }
}
```

The method may be called with an additional specifier telling the compiler to *infer* the argument type of the first and second parameter:

```
List<Box<Integer>> listOfIntegerBoxes = new ArrayList<>(); 
BoxDemo.<Integer>addBox(Integer.valueOf(20), listOfIntegerBoxes);
```

also from the documentation:

> Alternatively, if you omit the type witness,a Java compiler automatically infers (from the method's arguments) that the type parameter is Integer:

```
BoxDemo.addBox(Integer.valueOf(20), listOfIntegerBoxes);
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax here is because the `Specs` class's `satisfyAll` method is `static`, so the `Generics` syntax there is specifying the type to use for the static method.

See this for the API doc: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/specs/Specs.html#satisfyAll%28%29